# Device receive notification but never appears on my device

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a problem similar to:
[iOS not receiving notifications from Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41242916/ios-not-receiving-notifications-from-firebase-cloud-messaging)

In my `Firebase console` I added from my KeyChain my Apple iOS Development Push Service `.p12` key also, I added the `GoogleService-Info.plist` and the identifiers are ok.

Also, in my `Capabilities` the `Push Notifications`, `Background Modes` > `Background fetch` and `Remote notifications` and `Keychain Sharing` are active.

And my **AppDelegate.swift** looks:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
//import FacebookCore
import FBSDKCoreKit
import UserNotifications
import Firebase
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseInstanceID
import FirebaseMessaging

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
        GMSServices.provideAPIKey("xxxx-xxx")


        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })

            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
            FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self

        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        // [END register_for_notifications]
        FIRApp.configure()

        // [START add_token_refresh_observer]
        // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
        //NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification), name: .firInstanceIDTokenRefresh, object: nil)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification), name: NSNotification.Name.firInstanceIDTokenRefresh, object: nil)


        return true
    }

    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        //return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options)
        let appId = FBSDKSettings.appID()
        if url.scheme != nil && url.scheme!.hasPrefix("fb\(appId)") && url.host ==  "authorize" { // facebook
            //return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options)
            return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options)
        }
        return false;
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
        FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    }

    func connectToFcm() {
        FIRMessaging.messaging().connect { (error) in
            if (error != nil) {
                print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(error)")
            } else {
                print("Connected to FCM.")
            }
        }
    }

    /*func connectToFcm() {
        // Won't connect since there is no token
        guard FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() != nil else {
            return;
        }

        // Disconnect previous FCM connection if it exists.
        FIRMessaging.messaging().disconnect()

        FIRMessaging.messaging().connect { (error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(error)")
            } else {
                print("Connected to FCM.")
            }
        }
    }*/

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        FIRMessaging.messaging().disconnect()
        print("Disconnected from FCM.")
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification

        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification

        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        // Let FCM know about the message for analytics etc.
        FIRMessaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        // handle your message
    }

    func tokenRefreshNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() {
            print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
        }

        // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
        connectToFcm()
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

        var token = ""
        for i in 0..<deviceToken.count {
            token = token + String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [deviceToken[i]])
        }

        //Tricky line
        FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.sandbox)
        print("Device Token:", token)
        print("Token:", deviceToken)


        // With swizzling disabled you must set the APNs token here.
        // FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.sandbox)
    }


}


// [START ios_10_message_handling]
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        // Change this to your preferred presentation option
        completionHandler([])
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        completionHandler()
    }
}
// [END ios_10_message_handling]
// [START ios_10_data_message_handling]
extension AppDelegate : FIRMessagingDelegate {
    // Receive data message on iOS 10 devices while app is in the foreground.
    func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print(remoteMessage.appData)
    }
}
// [END ios_10_data_message_handling]
```

When I sent a message from the `Firebase` console I get a message like:

```
Message ID: 0:1xxxx5994%84df84xxxxx
[AnyHashable("google.c.a.e"): 1, AnyHashable("google.c.a.ts"): 14871xxx, AnyHashable("google.c.a.udt"): 0, AnyHashable("gcm.n.e"): 1, AnyHashable("aps"): {
    alert = "This is a test";
}, AnyHashable("google.c.a.c_id"): 5884120750xxxxxx, AnyHashable("gcm.message_id"): 0:1xxxx5994%84df84xxxxx]
```

But for some reason the push notification never appears on my device.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: try adding title and sound from firebase console (advanced options)

Comment: You're right! @ConstantinSaulenco

Comment: You won't be seeing the notification if the app is open. You are having this trouble with the app in foreground or in background?

Comment: When the app is open @Juan Curti

Comment: Then check the console log. If the app is open the notification wont appear in the device